# .NET Web API OWIN Authentication with VueJS

Tags: asp.net-web-api, vuejs2, owin, windows-authentication

I am trying to develop a VueJS SPA app with WebApi 2 as backend and would like to implement OWIN authentication.

The front end app should be accessible to intranet users (Windows authentication) and based on the roles (already existing table that is stored in the database- which I would like to add to claims), the corresponding pages should be accessible to user.

Most of the examples use Forms Authentication, which return token, which are not helpful in my situation

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ for token based authentication.